# Set operations using a specific comparison rule

Tags: c#, .net, linq, set

I have two lists:

```
List<User> collection1 = new List<User>();
List<User> collection2 = new List<User>();
```

1) I have to get all items common to both of the lists using LINQ. However, the class `User` has a lot of properties and I just want to compare `FirstName` and `LastName`.

2) How can I get the items in `collection1` but not in `collection2` using the same comparison rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) for the first question and [Enumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) for the second. To wit:

```
var common = collection1.Intersect(collection2, new UserEqualityComparer());
var difference = collection1.Except(collection2, new UserEqualityComparer());
```

Here, of course, I am assuming that `UserEqualityComparer` implements `IEqualityComparer<User>` like so:

```
class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User> {
    public bool Equals(User x, User y) {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (x == null || y == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return x.FirstName == y.FirstName && x.LastName == y.LastName;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(User obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 23 * obj.FirstName.GetHashCode() + obj.LastName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to explicitly define the `GetHashCode` method?  I've done this before but don't remember needing to do that.

Comment: @Kirk: You have to provide an implementation of `GetHashCode` to satisfy the `IEqualityComparer<>` interface, and since `Intersect` and `Except` will almost certainly be calling it then you need to make sure that you implement it properly!